# Can I only allow a single API Key to access a single AWS API Gateway endpoint?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I want one of my endpoints to only be available to a single api key. For all others, I want to reject it.

I have been looking around and it seems that you can do this by IAM account or IP address but I can't find anything about API Key. Is this possible?

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood your question. No there is no way to configure different API keys on different methods (endpoints) in an API. You will need to write custom code to authenticate it probably using custom header e.g. `x-my-custom-key`. `Request` based Lambda Authorizer appears to be your best option.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can create an API key and attach it to an API Gateway endpoint.

1. Firstly create an API key.
   **AWS console** -> **API Gateway** -> **API Key** -> **Actions** -> **Create API Key.**
2. Now Import an API key, **API Gateway -> API Key -> Import API keys**. Type key in [format](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-key-file-format.html).
3. In API Gateway Methods(Get/Post) -> In Method request set **API Ket Required** to **true**.
4. Now create an usage plan: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-create-usage-plans-with-console.html
5. Deploy the API.

AWS doc: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-setup-api-key-with-console.html

You can also follow: https://datanextsolutions.com/blog/protect-aws-api-gateway-endpoints-using-api-keys/

Comment: This doesn't explain how I can only allow specific usage plan or api key to access a resource.

Comment: Create a usage plan, in deatils you can see the Lambda function API. And in tab API keys you can see which key you have binded with the API.

Answer (score 0):

> "I can't find anything about API Key. Is this possible?"

Yes it is.

1. Create a usagePlan, associate it with you API-Stage that you want to protect.
2. Create an API Key and associate it to a usage plan.
3. Mark the apiKey required field as true on the methods in your API.
4. Deploy your API.

Now your API methods will only execute if the correct X-API-Key header is passed in the request, every other request will get a forbidden status.